# Gradle build unsuccessful in android after Updation to 3.0.1

Tags: android, ubuntu, gradle, react-native

I updated my android studio because my react native app was not loading and after updation , I saw that gradle build is not loading due to the error shown in the screenshot.

I tried all the suggestions provided in the error log. Please help. 
I am working on ubuntu 16.04
The screeen shot is attached:- [check the image for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKbEt.png)

I am not able to save my project even . i am not able to understand how should i proceed to solve this. Check the image for checking out the error.

1.[image of android studio error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNZB1.png)

The gradle build is showing this as output

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug]
```

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
  >   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir(Ljava/io/File;)V
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:87)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:82)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:69)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:103)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:49)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:651)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:133)
  at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
  at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:60)
  at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:100)
  at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:81)
  at org.gradle.execution.commandline.CommandLineTaskParser.parseTasks(CommandLineTaskParser.java:42)
  at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:44)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
  at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:36)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$CalculateTaskGraph.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:265)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.constructTaskGraph(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:173)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:128)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:107)
  at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
  at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
  at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
  at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:53)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:71)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:58)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:33)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
  at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
  Caused by: org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
  at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:86)
  at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
  at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
  at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
  at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
  at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:75)
  ... 95 more
  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir(Ljava/io/File;)V
  at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.JavaCompileConfigAction.execute(JavaCompileConfigAction.java:131)
  at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.JavaCompileConfigAction.execute(JavaCompileConfigAction.java:39)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.create(DefaultTaskContainer.java:148)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskContainerAdaptor.create(TaskContainerAdaptor.java:59)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.AndroidTaskRegistry.create(AndroidTaskRegistry.java:47)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.AndroidTaskRegistry.create(AndroidTaskRegistry.java:89)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.createJavacTask(TaskManager.java:1102)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApplicationTaskManager$13.call(ApplicationTaskManager.java:248)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApplicationTaskManager$13.call(ApplicationTaskManager.java:241)
  at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
  at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApplicationTaskManager.createTasksForVariantData(ApplicationTaskManager.java:238)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createTasksForVariantData(VariantManager.java:485)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$3.call(VariantManager.java:293)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$3.call(VariantManager.java:290)
  at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
  at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders.record(SpanRecorders.java:44)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createAndroidTasks(VariantManager.java:286)
  at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$11.call(BasePlugin.java:688)
  at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$11.call(BasePlugin.java:685)
  at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
  at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
  at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:683)
  at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:608)
  at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:605)
  at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
  at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
  at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$1(BasePlugin.java:603)
  at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
  at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
  at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
  at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
  at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
  at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
  ... 102 more
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s

Comment: could you post your gradle stack trace?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque I am new to android. Can you please guide me how to check the console of android after giving the command --stacktrace in the Compilers Settings of Android.

Comment: There´s a gradle console tab in Android Studio where the result of your gradle build will show. The tab is in the lower right side of the screen.

Comment: Yes @LeviAlbuquerque. But that is blank. it is not displaying any message. How to see messages there?

Comment: open the console and run build your app

Comment: the gradle build is giving this as output : -

Comment: Please chcek my gradle console log. I have posted it as an answer. Everything was fine until i updated my android-studio. My react native app was running fine.

Comment: you need to edit your initial post and include the things you posted as answers. You´re violating the good practices of StackOverlow use and a moderator and other users might downvote you.

Comment: do you have write/read permission for the folder where android studio is saved? What about your project folder?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistakes. I have rectified those.

Comment: Yes i set the permissions as read and write. please help me as to why the gradle sync is failing

Comment: Hi, could you post your gradle files? Both project and app level?

Comment: Yes I have posted that only. Because in android i open my react native project.and that project's gradle build failed.I am thinking of reinstalling android studio once again. What is the best way to uninstall android studio